# How to add all new folders and files to Git?

Tags: git

I cloned a repo, and then copied a folder containing many subfolders and files into it.

I then ran git add .

However, this just added a single, empty folder to the repository.

Is there a way to add everything recursively? I've tried git add -A and git add -u, they don't seem to work.

Thanks!

Comment: can you show the result of `git status`? And the git version would be useful too

Comment: Do the subfolders themselves perhaps have a `.git` directory (meaning you ran `git init` on them before copying)?

Comment: Actually yes! Presumably I should delete the .git directory there?

Comment: Yes. Git cannot track the contents of folders that themselves are being tracked by git.

Comment: If you want to keep them as separate repositories (maybe a library being included in your main program) you can look into `submodule`s or `subtree`s

Comment: Thanks Nils - deleting the .git will be fine here. What a silly mistake!

Comment: Not silly -- not even clearly a mistake.  Nested repositories are called submodules, there's a command to help with them, they're very useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the comments under your question: The folders you copied into your repository were repositories themselves (meaning they had a `.git` folder in them).

Git will not allow you to re-track files that already are being tracked by another git repository.

Answer (score 0):

Nils has answered this!

I had accidentally copied another .git folder into the repo.

Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Keep in mind that you cannot add folders under revision. The only thing you can add to git is content.

If you want to add empty folders. Add empty files in them and add them to git however you want.

One trick to add everything you want is to use the interactive mode of git.

```
git add -i
```

if you press numbers, you can switch from one menu to the other

```
2) Add changes
3) Revert changes
4) Untracked files
5) Patch
```

I suggest to explore this command.

When you are in a menu, enter the number of the file in the list.

Ranges are also accepted. like 1-10 will select files from 1 to 10.

-5-7 will unselect files from 5 to 7

Also if some files aren't visible in the lists, but should be visible check that you don't have a gitignore file somewhere that hides them.

Comment: Thanks - the new folder isn't empty. There are thousands of files and subfolders under it, but they weren't added.

Comment: The OP mentioned "folder containing many subfolders and files", so that doesn't seem to be the issue here.

Comment: Ah right, I wouldn't have tought of .git below, these directories are added to the the revision control but it should be handled with submodules. So each revision is kept in its own project.